# SQL in VB.net showing wrong dates

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

In VS2017 I am pulling dates from an Access accdb file to show in a ReportViewer. However, all of my date queries pull all of the fields in each date regardless of what I put in the variables.

Here is the input formatting and var run

```vb
SignupDateStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
SignupDateStart.CustomFormat = "MM / dd / yyyy"
Dim strSignupDateStart As String = SignupDateStart.ToString
strSignupDateStart = lblStartDate.Text

SignupDateEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
SignupDateEnd.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
Dim strSignupDateEnd As String = SignupDateEnd.ToString
strSignupDateEnd = lblEndDate.Text

frmSignupReportQuery2.getFilterValues(strSignupDateStart, strSignupDateEnd)
```

Here is the `getFilterValues` sub:

```vb
Public Shared Sub getFilterValues(ByVal date1 As String, ByVal date2 As String)
    Try
        frmSignupReportQuery2.MemberBaseTableAdapter.
            FillBy(frmSignupReportQuery2.DataSet2.MemberBase, date1, date2)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

and here is the query i use for dataset2

```sql
SELECT  ID, ccnumberexp, EntireName, address, stateinit, zip, age, email, ccnumber, SignupDate, MemberTypes
FROM    MemberBase
WHERE   SignupDate BETWEEN #?# AND #?#
```

This is a school project and so any vulnerabilities are not a issue. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the vb.net code

```
Public strMembershipType As String = ""
Public strMembershipTypeNum As String = ""

    SignupDateStart.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    SignupDateStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    strSignupDateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(SignupDateStart.Value)
    MessageBox.Show(strSignupDateStart)

    SignupDateEnd.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    SignupDateEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    strSignupDateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(SignupDateEnd.Value)
    MessageBox.Show(strSignupDateEnd)

    frmSignupReportQuery2.getFilterValues(strSignupDateStart, strSignupDateEnd)
    frmSignupReportQuery2.Show()
```

I am now getting an *"InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid."* Error on the 
***strSignupDateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(SignupDateStart.Value)*** line

Here is the revised query

```
SELECT  ID, ccnumberexp, EntireName, address, stateinit, zip, age, email, 
ccnumber, SignupDate, MemberTypes
FROM    MemberBase
WHERE   SignupDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

**EDIT 2**

The class I am taking is not for programming, it is analysis of system design and projects. The teacher I have does not know how to do what I am doing. Most others in my class are using some mix of MSaccess. I wish I had someone to show me how to do parameterized queries in datasets, But I will get to it. This is my current implementation.

```
    Try

        SignupQuery.ReportViewer1.Clear()
        SignupQuery.getFilterValues(SignupDateStart.Value, SignupDateEnd.Value)
        SignupQuery.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        SignupQuery.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

Public Shared Sub getFilterValues(ByVal date1 As Date, ByVal date2 As Date)
    Try
```

here is the subprocedure:

```
SignupQuery.MemberBaseTableAdapter.FillBy(SignupQuery.DataSet2.MemberBase, 
date1, date2)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
end sub
```

I appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: What is `#?#` ?  Please see how to include a **[mcve]**.  Also if a good idea to search for existing answers to similar questions.  Obviously "specifying date criteria" is a going to be a very common task, ans therefore will likely have numerous examples of working code available to you online.

Comment: That SQL makes no sense.  `#` symbols are for date literals while `?` symbols are for parameters, so the two are mutually exclusive.  If you're using parameters, as appears to be the case, then get rid of the `#` symbols.  Those symbols are the date equivalent of single quotes for strings.  Do you put single quotes around the `?` for a string parameter?  I would hope not.

Comment: the # are not there anymore, They were there because I am just throwing stuff at it to see if I get any difference.

Comment: "any vulnerabilities are not a issue." Vulnerabilities are always an issue. Why learn the wrong way to do something? Use Parameters.

Comment: " pull all of the fields " I think you mean pull all the records. Vocabulary is important when trying to discuss programming issues. Fields are the columns in each record.

Answer (score 1):

First, do use parameters. School or not, you will have to learn that anyway, sooner or later.

But, if you insist on concatenating, your code can be reduced to:

```
strSignupDateStart = SignupDateStart.Value.ToString("#yyyy'/'MM'/'dd#")
MessageBox.Show(strSignupDateStart)

strSignupDateEnd = SignupDateEnd.Value.ToString("#yyyy'/'MM'/'dd#")
MessageBox.Show(strSignupDateEnd)

frmSignupReportQuery2.getFilterValues(strSignupDateStart, strSignupDateEnd)
frmSignupReportQuery2.Show()
```

This will pick the true DateTime values of the DateTimePickers and convert these to string expressions using a format understood by Access SQL: `#yyyy/mm/dd#`

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the dates to strings. If you ever find yourself converting a date to a string for use with an SQL database, you're doing something very wrong.

This is partly for security issues, but it's also just make things easier. Rely on the features of the dataset and ADO.Net to handle the formatting for your SQL dates. Give them a .Net DateTime value, and they already know how to convert it to make sure it's exactly what your database needs. This will also nicely side-step the problem you have here. But as this is for school, I'd like to see you make your own attempt before I show you any code.

I also wonder about this:

```
Dim strSignupDateStart As String = SignupDateStart.ToString
strSignupDateStart = lblStartDate.Text
```

and this:

```
Dim strSignupDateEnd As String = SignupDateEnd.ToString
strSignupDateEnd = lblEndDate.Text
```

In both cases, you initialize a new string variable to a value from a DatePicker control, and then immediately overwrite that string variable with a value from a label, such that the initialization from the previous line has no effect.

Comment: how to I turn this into a datetime value? Also I have removed the lblstartdate and lblenddate.

Comment: my apologies I did not see the bottom of what you wrote. I will attach an edit

Comment: As to "how to" get datetime value, you almost have it! `DateTimePicker.Value` will return a date.